# How to include Hy code inside python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hy

For example we have this Hy code:

```
(print "Hy, world!")
```

And we have two pieces of Python code. Piece one:

```
print("Some python code")
```

Piece two:

```
print("Some other python code")
```

How can we make something like this:

```
print("Some python code")
(print "Hy, world!")
print("Some other python code")
```

Please also include appropriate imports. I have not found right way to import `Hy`.

Comment: In general, it is not possible to mix both languages in the same file, because the resulting three lines here are not a valid program---neither for Python nor for Hy.  You actually have to put your Hy code into a separate file, and then import that using Hy.

Comment: @Tobias Maybe you know answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841891/how-to-include-hy-code-into-a-separate-file-and-then-import-that-using-hy  I am just starting Hy and I do not know how to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the manual:](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/interop.html#evaluating-strings-of-hy-code-from-python)

```
import hy

print("Some python code")
hy.eval(hy.read('(print "Hy, world!")'))
print("Some other python code")
```

Note that the Hy code is compiled at run-time. We'll probably never be able to implement embedding Hy code in a Python script so that it can be compiled at the same time the Python code is compiled. You can do the reverse and embed Python in Hy, though:

```
(pys "print('Some python code')")
(print "Hy, world!")
(pys "print('Some other python code')")
```

Comment: May I take this opportunity and suggest to add this information also to the tutorial in your documentation?  Currently, the tutorial only describes the language, but not how to actually use/run it, which leaves a new user somewhat puzzled.

Comment: Does that `Hy code is compiled at run-time` means that there is performance penalty on second and later runs of hy code?

Comment: I agree with Tobias. I looked at tutorial and it is hard to understand what to do. However  your answer here is very clear.

Comment: @vasili111 Yes, `hy.eval` is slow, so if the Hy code would run more than once per executation of the overall Python program, wrap it in a `(defn …)` and call the newly created function from Python.

Comment: Thank you. I should wrap my Hy program in a `(defn …)` and put it in separate file as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61841983/1601703? Or there is a way to include `(defn …)` in same python file?

Comment: Also if I wrap my Hy program in a `(defn …)` and call the newly created function from Python, there will not be performance penalty for second and following runs?

Comment: I mean that you could write something like `hy.eval(hy.read_str('(defn foo [] (print "Hy, world!"))'))` in Python, and then call `foo()`. There's no penalty because the Hy code is already compiled by the time you say `foo()`. Using a seperate file works fine, too, though. Importing a Hy module compiles it only once, even if you import it again.

Comment: @Kodiologist I am very sorry for this, but I somehow missed you last comment here which explains a lot and is very informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You put your `hy` code into a separate file and name it `example.hy` (or whatever):

```lisp
(print "Hello World")
```

Inside your Python-script, you then simply import `hy` first, and afterwards you import `example` just as you would with a Python module.

```py
import hy
import example
```

The reason this works is because `hy` installs an import hook when you do `import hy`, which allows it to find `hy`-files, compile them and then import them just like any other Python module.

Comment: Thank you. This answer belongs to this question. Please put it there so I can accept it.

Comment: I ment this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841891/how-to-include-hy-code-into-a-separate-file-and-then-import-that-using-hy