# How to include Hy code into a separate file, and then import that using Hy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hy

*I am just starting using Hy.*

For example we have this Hy code:

```
(print "Hy, world!")
```

And we have two pieces of Python code. Piece one:

```
print("Some python code")
```

Piece two:

```
print("Some other python code")
```

How to include Hy code into a separate file, and then import that using Hy?

Please include all necessary code and instructions (where to put what and how to run) for Hy part and Python parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Hy's manual on this](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/interop.html#using-hy-from-python) is a bit hidden (i.e. not part of the tutorial at the moment).

Anyway, you put your *Hy* code into a separate file and name it `example.hy` (or whatever):

```lisp
(print "Hy, world!")
```

Inside your Python-script, you then simply import `hy` first, and afterwards you import `example`, just as you would with a Python module.

```py
import hy
import example
```

The reason this works is because `hy` installs an [import hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) when you do `import hy`, which allows it to find `hy`-files, compile them and then import them just like any other Python module.  Of course, you can also do stuff like this:

```py
import hy
print("Some python code")
import example
print("Some other python code")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there performance penalty of using Hy this way?

Comment: @vasili111 No, there isn't.